# Why was this question moved to Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, migration, closed-questions

I answered this question, and have answered many like it which are related to programmatically configuring IIS:

> [Programmatically assigning an existing ssl cert to a website in iis6 via powershell or vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585809/programmatically-assigning-an-existing-ssl-cert-to-a-website-in-iis6-via-powershe?noredirect=1)

Why was this moved? How is it any different from these and many others written by myself and others:

> [Using ServerManager to create Application within Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518186/using-servermanager-to-create-application-within-application)
>
> [IIS: wwwroot directories of an IIS with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088928/iis-wwwroot-directories-of-an-iis-with-c)

I also notice that I don't get credited with the correct answer on SF for this question either.

I should also point out that having scanned the first 7 pages of the [IIS](https://serverfault.com/tags/iis) tag there's not a single PowerShell or C/VB Script in sight. I also know for a fact that the chap who asked the question is another developer.

I generally tend to find that these kinds of questions come from developers creating build and deployment scripts/code and not from sys admins.

As I pointed out to Adam below, I'm a developer and I specialise building shared-hosting provisioning systems for IIS 6 and 7. I think Jeff got this one wrong and surely the community should be deciding this through the proper channels of voting, not Jeff.

Comment: Good question.  While I don't think it is off-topic for SF, I do think it would be a better fit on stackoverflow since the question is about how to perform the a task programatically.

Comment: @zore programmatically *with a script* -- and not a developer build script either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I, and at least 2 other people -- including the person who flagged it and Pollyanna -- felt that question was *particularly* sysadmin-y.

Since the question lives on just fine on Server Fault with +2 upvotes, what exactly is the problem, again?

edit: rather than fight about it, I decided to unmigrate it. Meh.

Comment: The problem is that people on SO are much more likely to solve it than people on serverfault (I know, eventually it might get solved on either sites, but, its a better fit for SO - as I said - what the person wants to achieve is not as important as the approach he wants to take - which is scripting).

Answer (score 0):

Scripting is within the domain of IT just as much as (perhaps more than) programmers, and assigning certificates is certainly within the IT domain.  Therefore, on balance, it likely belongs more to SF than SO.

Comment: I disagree, it's not just an IT "scripting" question, it's about utilising an API to achieve a specific task. I doubt many IT admins will have heard of that API, not many programmers have.

Comment: Also if that's the case, every Q&A that mentions IIS configuration should be moved en-masse to Server Fault.

Comment: @kev - You might be surprised to find out that a lot of IT admins spend most of their time scripting to reduce errors involved in doing things manually.  This is exactly the type of question that a sysadmin would likely know better than a generic programmer - only programmers that have scripted for IIS would know this - by definition those people are system administrators.  Questions are moved on a case by case basis.  It appears your question was answered, though, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  Why does it matter whether its on one site or the other?

Comment: I answered the question and yes it does matter because I have a sizable body of work on SO about programmatically configuring IIS. I write and design IIS shared host provisioning systems for a living, let me tell you I've yet to see an IIS admin tackle automated SSL imports. This Q&A firmly belongs on SO amongst my other work.

Comment: @Kev Well, all you need to do is convince 4 other 3k+ rep people to reopen the question on SO. While I remain unconvinced with your arguments, chances are good that you'll find others around here that agree with you.  If you require immediate action, you can try chat - there are usually a bunch of people hanging around there that can act on such requests.

Comment: @pollyanna - are you trying to teach me to suck eggs with that last comment :)

Comment: @kev - Who, me?  I would never!  *whistles nonchalantly*

Comment: @Polly: 1) The question can't be reopened on SO by 3k rep users. 2) As both a developer and a sysadmin, I'm sick of hearing people try to distinguish between "programming" and "scripting". It's absurd and insulting. Please stop doing it.

Comment: @Nicholas - I'm sorry to have insulted you. I'm not going to insult you further and attempt to help you understand why I maintain a distinction, but I do want to assure you that in no way is it my intention to push the idea that scripting is not programming, or that the two are at odds, or that one is better or worse than the other.

Comment: The end-goal is not important. The approach is. If I want to programatically make an english dictionary, it should be on SO and not english.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Polly it is very frustrating that there is even a separation of coding/IT. All that says to me is that there is no faith in the tagging system. I AM the IT staff AND the developer-- the tasks are intertwined. Code runs on MACHINES & NETWORKS.